# The XPath id() function

Tags: xml, function, xpath

I can't find any good explanation of the `id()` function in XPath. What does it do? How do you use it?

From the available descriptions, it sounds like it will give you `id` of a node.

So I played with it like this, but got an error:

```
//bookstore/id(book)
```

Then got a little fancier and tried

```
//bookstore/book[name = id(book/@category)]
```

which didn't return an error, but got no hits.

Can someone explain this function for me, and future Stack fans and Googlers?

Here's the XML I'm playing with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J. K. Rowling</author>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<book category="OPENSOURCE">
  <title lang="en">Open Source</title>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">WEB</title>
  <year>2012</year>
  <price>21.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: You should play with a document that does contain `id` attributes, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that [based on the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-id) that you would only use the `id()` function if you have defined [unique IDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#unique-id) in your DTD.

> The id function selects elements by their unique ID.
>
> ...
>
> An element node may have a unique identifier (ID). This is the value of the attribute that is declared in the DTD as type ID.

I also came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889679/1078110) that discusses the ID type in a DTD and how to define that.

Answer (score 5):

> I can't find any good explanation

Let me recommend my book ;-).

I don't think the id() function will help you because I don't think your source document has any ID attributes. It has very few attributes, and those it has are not unique, so they cannot be IDs.